# Woocommerce: Allow "other" as a state or add options for provinces?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm working on a portal for a client and they need to be able to ship to Canada but there aren't any provinces listed in the select option, how would I go about adding those or adding the ability to fill a text box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add them manually. Check the code example. Basically, you're filtering inside woocommerce_states and editting them with your custom function.

```
/**
 * Code goes in functions.php or a custom plugin.
 */
add_filter( 'woocommerce_states', 'custom_woocommerce_states' );

function custom_woocommerce_states( $states ) {

  $states['XX'] = array(
    'XX1' => 'State 1', 
    'XX2' => 'State 2'
  );

  return $states;
}
```

Comment: Would this add to the states or overwrite them?

Comment: This will add. See you receive variable $states - which is the default. If you just return them without changing, then nothing will be changed. 

You can see easily by doing var_dump($states) and die; inside function.

Comment: If this solved your issue (and it should), accept so others can focus on other questions.